# Silent GnuPG password request with bash commands

Tags: terminal, io-redirection, gpg, output

I'm trying to hide the "output" of a gnupg command, but it seems that it is always printed.

the command is:

`echo "thisprogramwørks" | gpg -q --status-fd 1 --no-use-agent --sign --local-user D30BDF86 --passphrase-fd 0 --output /dev/null`

It is a command to verify the password of pgp keys, and by using it like this:

`a=$(echo "thisprogramwørks" | gpg -q --status-fd 1 --no-use-agent --sign --local-user D30BDF86 --passphrase-fd 0 --output /dev/null)`

I recover the output:

`echo $a
[GNUPG:] USERID_HINT F02346C1EA445B6A p7zrecover (7zrecover craking pgp test) <a@a> [GNUPG:] NEED_PASSPHRASE F02346C1EA445B6A F02346C1EA445B6A 1 0 [GNUPG:] GOOD_PASSPHRASE [GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING [GNUPG:] SIG_CREATED S 1 8 00 1435612254 8AE04850C3DA5939088BE2C8F02346C1EA445B6A`

the problem is that when I use the command, the console prints:

`You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "test (test) <a@a>"
1024-bit RSA key, ID EA445B6A, created 2015-06-29`

I've been trying to use command redirects like `&>/dev/null` and stuff like that, but passphrase text is always printed. It is possible to hide this text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "problem" is, that gpg writes directly to the TTY instead of STDOUT or STDERR. That means it cannot be redirected.

You can either use the `--batch` option as daniel suggested, but as a **more general approach** you can use the `script` tool, which fakes a TTY. Any output is then sent to STDOUT, so you can redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
script -c 'echo "thisprogramwørks" | gpg -q --status-fd 1 --no-use-agent --sign --local-user D30BDF86 --passphrase-fd 0 --output /dev/null' > /dev/null
```

The output is also written to a file, so you can still get and analyze it. See `man script` ([link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script))

Answer (score 3):

Add the `--batch` option.

If you would like to achieve the same result through redirection you would have to close STDIN through:

```
gpg … <&-
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gpg` manpage also lists a `--no-tty` option:

> --no-tty
>
> Make sure that the TTY (terminal) is never used for any output.  This option is needed in some cases because GnuPG sometimes  prints  warnings to the TTY even if --batch is used.

Comment: To add to this I found that some output was suppressed by this, but the rest can be by doing `gpg --no-tty ... 2> /dev/null` which redirects stderr only. I have no idea why info about the key used gets sent to stderr in the first place...